# Using any()/all() on 2d array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to solve this exercise and I would be pretty much finished if my while loop would work.
Just for context: The exercise was to develop a program which sends a few runners trough a grid until every point in the grid got touched. My grid is a 2d array, every time a runner gets to a new position the boolean value switches from True to False. When all of the positions in the array are touched (False), the while loop is supposed to stop. It doesn't.
Any(field) still returns True despite the fact that all boolean values in the array are on False.

```
field = stdarray.create2D(n, n, True)
field[middle][middle] = False
laeufer = stdarray.create2D(n, 2, middle)
while any(field):
    for x in range(n):
        step = 0
        if laeufer[x][0] == 0 and laeufer[x][1] == 0: \
                step = random.choice([0, 2])
        elif laeufer[x][0] == n - 1 and laeufer[x][1] == n - 1:
            step = random.choice([1, 3])
        elif laeufer[x][0] == 0 and laeufer[x][1] == n - 1:
            step = random.choice([0, 3])
        elif laeufer[x][0] == n - 1 and laeufer[x][1] == 0:
            step = random.choice([1, 2])
        elif laeufer[x][0] == 0:
            step = random.choice([0, 2, 3])
        elif laeufer[x][0] == n - 1:
            step = random.choice([1, 2, 3])
        elif laeufer[x][1] == 0:
            step = random.choice([0, 1, 2])
        elif laeufer[x][1] == n - 1:
            step = random.choice([0, 1, 3])
        else:
            step = random.randrange(0, 4)
        if step == 0:
            laeufer[x][0] += 1
        elif step == 1:
            laeufer[x][0] -= 1
        elif step == 2:
            laeufer[x][1] += 1
        else:
            laeufer[x][1] -= 1
        steps += 1
        test = not all(field)
        field[laeufer[x][0]][laeufer[x][1]] = False
```

I know, a lot of ifs but it works until the point of the while loop. It just continues running with an all False array instead of terminating.
Why isn't any() switching to False when there are no Trues left?

I hope you can help me.
Thanks,
Marcel

Edit:
From the debugger:

```
field = {list} <class ‚list‘>:[…]
__len__ = {int} 4
 0 = {list} <class ‚list‘>: [False, False, False, False]
 1 = {list} <class ‚list‘>: [False, False, False, False]
 2 = {list} <class ‚list‘>: [False, False, False, False]
 3 = {list} <class ‚list‘>: [False, False, False, False]
i = {int} 0
laeufer = {list} <class ‚list‘>: [[1, 1], [2, 2], [2, 0], [3, 2]]
n = {int} 4
runden = {int} 1000
step = {int} 3
steps = {int} 103
test = False
```

Comment: What is `stdarray`?

Comment: @user2357112: It seems to be a helper module for working with multi-dimension Python lists.  http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stdarray.py.html

Comment: How do you know all `field` values are `False`? A `list` with a value in it is truthy: `bool([False]) == True`

Comment: @Peter Wood I send it trough a debugger, so I know that at some point all of the boolean values are False but "any(field)" doesn't seem to care. It still has the value True, and "not any(field)" has still the Value False.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you iterate over a `list` of `list`s, you get lists.

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> for row in matrix:
...     print(row)
...
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Any non-empty list is “truthy” (i.e., makes the body of an `if` or `while` statement execute) even if all of its values are falsy.

```
if []:
    print("Won't execute: Empty list is falsy")

if [0, 0.0, False, '', b'']:
    print("Will execute: Non-empty list is truthy")
```

If you want to check if there is a truthy value anywhere in the two-dimensional list, you can use:

```
any(any(row) for row in matrix)
```

Comment: I tried the last command but it says False from almost the beginning (after the array is filled with False values)

Comment: Okay, I just did this:
`while True:
       if not (any(any(row) for row in field)):
            break`

Comment: or easier: `while (any(any(row) for row in field)):`

Comment: `while any(any(row) for row in field):` you don't need the extra parentheses.